# как изьять командой в mysql список прозвонных номеров?

Tags: mysql

вот команду которую вводил:

```
set @intr=12; 
select 
      dst, count(dst) as cnt 
from asteriskcdrdb.cdr 
where calldate >= SUBDATE( NOW(), INTERVAL @intr HOUR) 
      and billsec=0 and dst rlike '^998' 
group by dst 
order by cnt desc 
limit 30;
```

Comment: какую ошибку вы получаете? кроме этого, не все работают с астериксом, рекомендуем добавить пример дампа таблиц (например на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)), чтобы можно было увидеть какие данные вы хотите получить.

Comment: И что такое "Изъять" и какие номера называются "прозвонными" ?